# Using Dense Rank to simulate Count(Distinct) but running into a problem

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, dense-rank

Since SQL doesn't allow me to do count Distinct over Window functions, I have to use dense rank to achieve what I am trying to do.

My statement is:

```
,DENSE_RANK() over (partition by CustomerEmail order by Date_Created asc)
+DENSE_RANK() over (partition by CustomerEmail order by Date_Created desc)
-1 as AmountOrdersOverRangeByCustomer
```

This gives me how much time a customer (using email to identify) places an order. So if he places 5 orders over a period of time, it would go 5,5,5,5, and 5.

The problem is, if he places two orders on the same day (Date_Created). Then instead of counting it as 2,2,  Dense_Rank counts it as 1,1... which I think is how it is supposed to act, but not how I want it. Does anyone know a fix? Would using Row_Number instead of Dense_Rank fix this?

Comment: Your question is really incomplete, but there is no data backing what you are asking.  Please include some sample data, along with the output you would like to see.

Comment: @Natan . . . I think your code works.  Can you provide an example where it doesn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should work, although I more typically use a subquery for this purpose:

```
SELECT . . .
       MAX(dr) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerEmail) as AmountOrdersOverRangeByCustomer
FROM (SELECT . . .,
             DENSE_RANK() over (partition by CustomerEmail order by Date_Created asc) as dr
      . . .
     ) . . .
```

However, if you want to count two orders on the same day as two, rather than one, then perhaps you don't want `COUNT(DISTINCT)` at all, simply:

```
COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerEmail)
```

Comment: COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerEmail) is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your query is counting DISTINCT Date_Created for each customer email.
If you want to count "how much times a customer places an order" you should use regular count, like:

```
COUNT(*) over (partition by CustomerEmail)
```